# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, mysql-connector

[image: error here]

[image: controller here]

[image: service here]

'm not getting it at all, I already changed the database, I changed the project entities and nothing.I would like to understand what I am doing wrong to be able to make the post.I attended some courses to be able to understand how to do it and to do it works. Alone there is always something.If anyone can help me, thanks in advance. because the similar questions here on the stack are not related to postMapping

Comment: Never post images of code.

Comment: Your POST endpoint is expecting a single `BmiUser`, but you're passing an array.

Comment: when passing the json am I passing an array?

Comment: Ok, I managed to solve. thank you, and I will not post more photos kk

Comment: Yes, `[ ]` represents an array in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the [] in your request body, They represent that the data you transmitted is an array.